# Why can't I store data with my discord bot?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I set up MySQL for my discord.py bot.
I'm planning to do some small project to test myself on my friend server.

I want it to count how many messages are sent on a week, but it doesn't work.
It gives me this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rui\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rui\Desktop\Python\mudaenotifier\kyoreborn.py", line 40, in on_message
    cursor.execute(query,[(username)])
  File "C:\Users\Rui\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 257, in execute
    prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params)
  File "C:\Users\Rui\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 665, in prepare_for_mysql
    result = self._cmysql.convert_to_mysql(*params)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type Member cannot be converted
```

What can I do with this?

Here is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username=message.author
    print(username)
    query="SELECT * FROM messages WHERE username=%s"
    cursor.execute(query,[(username)])
    results=cursor.fetchall()
    if results:
        query="UPDATE messages SET messagecount = messagecount + 1 WHERE username = %s"
        cursor.execute(query,[(username)])
        con.commit()
        con.close()
    else:
        query = "INSERT INTO `messages`(username,messagecount) VALUES (%s,1)"
        cursor.execute(query, [(username)])
        con.commit()
        con.close()
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message.author` returns a `discord.Member` instance, use `str(message.author)` instead to cast it to a string.